# Write projection on non orthogonal subspaces in terms of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a real vector space and let $V_1, V_2$ be two non orthogonal subspaces such that $V_1+V_2=V$. Let $P$ be the projection onto $V_1$, i.e. $P^2=P$, $\mathrm{Im}(P)=V_1$, $\mathrm{Ker}(P)=V_2$. In some basis $\{v^1_1,\dots, v^1_k,v^2_1,\dots, v^2_n\}$ $P$ has the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}I&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

here $v^j_i$ forms an orthonormal basis of $V_j$. Now, looking at this matrix, my brain is **insisting** that then we must have

$$ P=\sum_{i=1}^kv^1_i{v_i^1}^T +\sum_{i=1}^k 0\cdot v^2_i{v_i^2}^T=\sum_{i=1}^kv^1_i{v_i^1}^T$$

After all this is what the matrix notation means, right? But this can't be right, as in this case any projector onto $V_1$ would be equal to the orthogonal projector. The problem is that this form of $P$ doesn't necessarily kill the vectors in the kernel. How then can I write down $P$ in terms of its eigenvectors?

Comment: I don't see the problem? What you wrote down does annihilate vectors in $V_2$, by orthogonality.

Comment: @operatorerror as I mentioned $V_1$ and $V_2$ aren't orthogonal, so the $v^2_j$ are not orthogonal to the $v^1_i$. Take e.g. both spaces to be one dimensional and spanned by $v_1=(1,0)$ and $v_2=(1,1)$, the correct projector is $$ \begin{pmatrix} 1&-1\\0&0 \end{pmatrix},$$ while $$v_1v_1^T=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$.

Comment: I missed the word non, but in the case that the $v_i$ are not orthogonal, you wont want the first part of your projection operator to be that in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Your brain is incorrect. Let $Q$ denote the matrix whose columns are $v_1^1,\dots,v_1^k,v_1^2,\dots,v^2_n$. The fact that $P$ has the form you present relative to this basis is equivalent to the statement that
$$
Q^{-1}PQ = \pmatrix{I & 0\\0 & 0} \implies P = Q\pmatrix{I &  0\\0 & 0}Q^{-1}.
$$
If the columns of $Q$ are **orthonormal** (which cannot be the case when $V_1,V_2$ are non-orthogonal), then we can write $Q^{-1} = Q^T$, which leads to the expanded sum that you found.